# Angular js bind model

Tags: php, angularjs

I started working on angular js. 
My problem is that I have a text field on which validation is performed, but I want to echo the value of this text field from Db but it is not working......

```
<input type="text"   pattern="[A-Za-z].{3,}"  required 
  name="uname" id="uname"  ng-minlength="4" ng-model="uname" class="txtbox-short"  value="<?php echo $unamedb; ?>"> 
<span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && xForm.uname.$error.required"></span>
<span class="help-inline" ng-show="xForm.uname.$error.minlength"  style="color:red;">Too Short!</span>
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the code instead of putting it in the comments, it will make it easier to read

Answer (score 1):

You should set `$scope.uname`. If you set your value like that `value="<?php echo $unamedb; ?>"`, than value in ng-model will be not `<?php echo $unamedb; ?>`. You should use `ng-init`. Like that `ng-init="uname=<?php echo $unamedb; ?>"`. Finish code input form:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z].{3,}" required name="uname" id="uname" ng-minlength="4" ng-model="uname" class="txtbox-short" ng-init="uname=<?php echo $unamedb; ?>">
```

Comment: and, sure, php echo isn't a better way to set data on input.